# Can User ask same question on DA and Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Is it valid to post Same Question (related to Drupal) on *Drupal Answers* and *Stack Overflow*?

If it's not valid, Can I flag such questions for moderator attention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is valid to crosspost the same question if it is going to be tailored for the site where the question is being asked; for example, a user could ask about a PHP library to achieve a Drupal task on Stack Overflow, and ask about a module to achieve the same task on Drupal Answers.

If you see the same exact question to be asked on both the sites, you could flag it for moderation attention, but you need to consider the following points:

- Was the question asked on Stack Overflow before Drupal Answers was a public beta site?
- Are the questions asked from the same user?
- Is a question a copy-pasta of the other one?
- Was one of the questions asked much later than the other one (e.g. 6 months later)?

In particular, if the questions are a copy-pasta, and asked in the same week, then flag it for moderation attention, using the "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" reason.

Those users who are asking the same question in two sites normally want a quick answer, and they are normally going to ignore one of the questions once they have an answer on the other site. This means they are engaging two different communities to then ignore any effort in helping.

Comment: Thank you moderators, kiamlaluno and @MPD :)